# Elasticsearch "strict" mapping not working for fields with null values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have an index for which I have set the mapping to `"dynamic":"strict"`.

As expected, for the most part, if a field that is not listed in the mapping is introduced, `Elasticsearch` will reject it.
However I am finding that any field with a `null` value is not caught, and will make it into my index. Here is what my mapping looks like:

```
{
 "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
       "mystuff": {
          "dynamic": "strict",
          "_id": {
             "store": true,
             "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "_timestamp": {
             "enabled": true,
             "store": true
          },
          "_index": {
             "enabled": true
          },
          "_type": {
             "store": true
          },
          "properties": {
             "entitlements": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                   "accountNumber": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed"
                   },
                   "active": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed"
                   },
                   "assetEndDate": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "format": "date_time_no_millis"
                   }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

EDIT (including example scenarios)

With the mapping above, here are the scenarios I am seeing:

1) When Posting a valid document (one that follows the mapping), `200 OK`.

posted document:

```
{
    "entitlements": [
        {
            "accountNumber": "123213",
            "active": "true",
            "assetEndDate": "2016-10-13T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

elasticsearch response:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mystuff",
  "_id": "5",
  "_version": 1,
  "created": true
}
```

2) When posting an invalid document (one that does not follow the mapping), `400 StrictDynamicMappingException`.

posted document:

```
{
  "entitlements": [
    {
      "accountNumber":"123213",
      "XXXXactive": "true",
      "assetEndDate": "2016-10-13T00:00:00Z"
    }     
  ] 
}
```

elasticsearch response:

```
{
 "error": "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [Xactive] within [entitlements] is not allowed]",
 "status": 400
}
```

3) When posting an invalid document (one that does not follow the mapping) with a value that is `null` for the invalid field, `200 OK`.

posted document:

```
{
  "entitlements": [
    {
      "accountNumber":"123213",
      "XXXXactive": null,
      "assetEndDate": "2016-10-13T00:00:00Z"
    }     
  ] 
}
```

elasticsearch response:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mystuff",
  "_id": "7",
  "_version": 1,
  "created": true
}
```

4) When posting an invalid document (one that does not follow the mapping) with a value that is `null` for the invalid field, `200 OK`.

posted document:

```
{
  "entitlements": [
    {
      "accountNumber":"123213",
      "XXXXactive": null,
      "assetEndDate": "2016-10-13T00:00:00Z",
      "THIS_SHOULD_NOT_BE_HERE": null
    }     
  ] 
}
```

elasticsearch response:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mystuff",
  "_id": "9",
  "_version": 1,
  "created": true
}
```

It is the 3rd and 4th scenarios, that I am concerned about.

It looks like this issue (or one very similar) was raised one the `Elasticsearch` git repository [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9444) and has since been closed. However, the problem appears to still be an issue in version 1.7 .

This is being seen locally, as well as on indexes I have deployed with AWS `Elasticsearch` Service.

Am I making a mistake somewhere, or Has anyone found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Tested this with 1.7.2. I'm not seeing the problem. Or you are not describing the issue properly. I'm seeing the mapping, but I don't see the failing test in your post.

Comment: Same here, tested with 1.7.1 and 1.7.3 and no issue.